# PDO prepared statement 'where' issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to `PDO` and I'm struggling to use the 'where' statement in a prepared statement. Below is the code I tried. It returns Data could not be retrieved from the database.

Can anyone tell me what the issue is? Anything to try etc?

Appreciate it!

```
$user_id = 1;

try {
    $query = $db->prepare("
            SELECT title, img, id
            FROM listings
            ORDER BY id DESC
            WHERE userID = :user_id
            LIMIT 2");
$query->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
    exit;
} 

$data = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return $data;
```

UPDATE: I swapped the `order` & `where` clause, but it still returns nothing (as oppose to the previous error message).

Comment: Why don't you inspect the exception, `$e`, to see what was the problem?

Comment: I suggest you to show an example to us through this: http://sqlfiddle.com/ at least you can see if the query is ok.

Comment: Please don't do that with exceptions. Just let them go at this low level. Catch them higher up if you must but for development work, you're going to want to know all the details of a `PDOException`. Also, if you've changed your code, update your question

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6c94/5

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite your query like this. [*You need to put ORDER BY clause after the WHERE* ]

```
   $query = $db->prepare("
            SELECT title, img, id
            FROM listings
            WHERE userID = :user_id
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 2");
```

Comment: Thanks, that removes the error message. But now it returns nothing, just a blank screen. Could there be an issue in the other code?

Comment: @AlexDanieli Yes. We can't see what you do with `$data` once it's returned

Comment: @Phil it's inside a function, even if i just do this:

print_r(get_products_userDashboard());

it returns nothing

Comment: @AlexDanieli Nothing as in *nothing at all*? Try `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. Also, remove the `try` and `catch` block

Comment: @Phil cheers, got it working. There was an issue with starting the session twice (a file was getting included twice).

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY id DESC` need to be added after `where` condition.

```
$query = $db->prepare("
            SELECT title, img, id
            FROM listings               
            WHERE userID = :user_id
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 2");
```

**Mysql Generic Select syntax:**

```
   SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that removes the error message. But now it returns nothing, just a blank screen. Could there be an issue in the other code?

Answer (score 0):

where clause should be before the order clause
Try this

```
$query = $db->prepare("
            SELECT title, img, id
            FROM listings
            WHERE userID = :user_id
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 2");
```

Comment: Thanks, that removes the error message. But now it returns nothing, just a blank screen. Could there be an issue in the other code?